# Cannot receive multicast RIST stream using RIST protocol, but RTP works

Tags: streaming, gstreamer

I'm using gstreamer to multicast a RIST stream:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=test.mts ! tee name=t ! queue ! typefind ! rtpmp2tpay ! ristsink address=239.255.0.1 port=5004 t. ! queue ! tsdemux ! fakesink sync=true
```

Then on my client, I'm converting the RIST stream to standard RTP and testing it in VLC:

```
gst-launch-1.0 ristsrc address=239.255.0.1 port=5004 ! queue ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5010
```

This doesn't work, the stream doesn't play. But if I instead receive it via rtpsrc, it works:

```
gst-launch-1.0 rtpsrc address=239.255.0.1 port=5004 ! queue ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5010
```

Keep in mind I'm still using ristsink on my server, but receiving with rtpsink.

Similarly, in VLC if I try to play `rist://@239.255.0.1:5004` it fails. But `rtp://@239.255.0.1:5004` works.

If I use an RTP receiver, I'll lose out on the benefits of RIST. So I'm keen to get this setup working with ristsrc and rist://, but I can't work out what I'm missing.

EDIT:

If I use unicast, RIST seems to work fine.

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=shadient.ts ! tee name=t ! queue ! typefind ! rtpmp2tpay ! ristsink address=127.0.0.1 port=5004 t. ! queue ! tsdemux ! fakesink sync=true

gst-launch-1.0 ristsrc address=127.0.0.1 port=5004 ! queue ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5010
```

Answer (score 0):

This one ended up having an easy solution. I just had to set `multicast-loopback` to true in `ristsrc` on the receiving end. I'm not too sure why this works though, I'd love if anyone has an explanation.